# android alert dialog box- not able to remove defaut blue line

Tags: android, dialog

I am using custom dialog and I want to remove this blue line. How can I do this?

I tried  `alert.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` and some other method but no effects

below code is not working!

```
int divierId = alert.getContext().getResources()
                .getIdentifier("android:id/titleDivider", null, null);
View divider = alert.findViewById(divierId);
divider.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.creamcolor));
```

[image: this image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to hide the blue line title divder alertdialog?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853970/how-to-hide-the-blue-line-title-divder-alertdialog)

Answer (score 0):

that blue line in alert dialog is divider between title and message
this will change divider color you can set Color.Transperent to hide it

```
    int divierId = alert.getContext().getResources()
                    .getIdentifier("android:id/titleDivider", null, null);
    View divider = alert.findViewById(divierId);
    divider.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.creamcolor));
```

Comment: Please explain your answer

Answer (score 0):

I got the Solution to get reference to titledivider of alertdialog to change its color using below code.Hope this helps somebody.

```
int divierId = dialog.getContext().getResources()
                .getIdentifier("android:id/titleDivider", null, null);
View divider = dialog.findViewById(divierId);
divider.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to hide the default blue line:

```
    Dialog dialog = getDialog();
    if (dialog != null) {
        final int dividerId = dialog.getContext().getResources()
                .getIdentifier("android:id/titleDivider", null, null);
        View divider = dialog.findViewById(dividerId);
        if  (divider != null) {
            divider.setBackground(null);
        }
    }
```